# "reserves is" VS "reserves are"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Foreign-exchange reserves (also called forex reserves or FX reserves) **is** money or other assets held by a central bank or other monetary authority.
> 2. Foreign-exchange reserves (also called forex reserves or FX reserves) **are** money or other assets held by a central bank or other monetary authority.

Why would plural form be used when reserve is in its plural form?

Would the same rule apply to oil reserves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Foreign-exchange reserves (also called forex reserves or FX reserves) **is** money or other assets held by a central bank or other monetary authority.

This is not grammatically correct. Reserves are plural, so the verb should be plural as well.

> 2.Foreign-exchange reserves (also called forex reserves or FX reserves) **are** money or other assets held by a central bank or other monetary authority.

This is grammatically correct.

**The same would apply for oil reserves:**

> Oil reserves are hard to measure because some countries intentionally misreport their reserves.